# Flutter Image - Connection terminated during handshake

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to pull a profile picture from a website. First of all, my code is as follows;

```
  Widget authorAvatarName() {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Image.network('https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/675e8f6e91740a40a4c12abbbd03ef75?s=96&d=https%3A%2F%2Fshiftdelete.net%2Fwp-content%2Fthemes%2Fshiftdelete%2Fassets%2Fimg%2Favatar.png&r=g',
          width: 32,
          height: 32,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          loadingBuilder: (context, child, loadingProgress) {
            if (loadingProgress == null) {
              return child;
            }
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          },
        ),
        const SizedBox(width: 8),
        Text(
          postDetailProvider.authorName,
          style: TextStyles.smallTextStyle.copyWith(
            color: isDarkMode == true
                ? ColorConstants.lightGrey
                : ColorConstants.darkBlack,
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

This code give the error;

```
Failed host lookup
Connection terminated during handshake
```

How can I fix the error?

I don't know why, but I guess it gives an error because it redirects to a different URL when logging into the image address.

Answer (score 0):

The code block you gave works and prints the picture to the screen. Since this error is related to internet connection, you need to add errorBuilder to avoid console error.

```
errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
  return const CircleAvatar(
    child: Icon(Icons.person), // or Image.asset('assets/images/shiftdeletelogo.png')
  );
},
```

Edit :

Assuming you add the following permission to your AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

As I mentioned above, I don't get any error with the url you shared.

Tested code block;

```
Image.network(
   'https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/675e8f6e91740a40a4c12abbbd03ef75?s=96&d=https%3A%2F%2Fshiftdelete.net%2Fwp-content%2Fthemes%2Fshiftdelete%2Fassets%2Fimg%2Favatar.png&r=g',
   height: 100,
   width: 100,
   loadingBuilder: (context, child, loadingProgress) {
     if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
     return Center(
       child: Stack(
         alignment: Alignment.center,
         children: [
           Text(loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes != null ? '% ${((loadingProgress.cumulativeBytesLoaded / loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes!) * 100).toInt()}' : ''),
           SizedBox(
             height: 100,
             width: 100,
             child: CircularProgressIndicator(
               value: loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes != null ? loadingProgress.cumulativeBytesLoaded / loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes! : null,
               backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
               valueColor: const AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.amber),
             ),
           ),
         ],
       ),
     );
   },
   errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
     return const CircleAvatar(
       child: Icon(Icons.person),
     );
   },
 ),
```

In my experiments, I did it by reducing the internet type and shooting power of the emulator or by cutting the internet while it was loading. There is no error.

Comment: Hello. I added `errorBuilder` to the code but I still get the same error

Comment: When I turn off the device's internet, errorBuilder prevents the next error for me. You can write to me on ig:alkanhakki in order to better understand the situation you are experiencing. In this way, I can identify the problem before the subject gets dirty, and make the solution available to both you and other users by editing my own message.

Comment: Hello. We can try to solve it from here.